# Can't enable share on clients in my network

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain-controller, file-sharing, network-share

I installed on my subnet a win 2003 server as the domain controller, with DHCP and DNS options too.
the clients, win xp pro and and win 2003 server.  In my clients when i log in via the domain, i don't have the option to share folders in the network! I want to share folders this way: 
right click on the folder > Properties > Sharing > Share

How can I make it appear? If I log in to the computer as the administrator I do have this option?

p.s.
please be specific for how to enable it, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

"if i log in to the computer as the administrator i do have this option"

Check your user rights and/or policies.

Comment: how and where to check it? in the domain controller machine? and where exactly?

Comment: You described the challenges occurring when the users are logged into the domain, so AD and possibly the local machine.

Comment: The following may be what you are looking for in order to "undo" the security defaults - http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/190158-46-create-shared-folders-domain-user-rights.